# Enable OPTIONS command in Varnish 4

Tags: varnish

Does anybody know the specific configuration directives for Varnish 4 which can enable this?

If I do: curl -v  'http://SERVER/nps.json' -X OPTIONS

Right now for my varnish I get back

```
    <h2>The server returned a "405 Method Not Allowed".</h2>
```

If I try to access the Apache behind it I get:

```
     Allow: POST,OPTIONS,GET,HEAD
```

So it is Varnish which blocks the OPTION requests.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is probably blocked by your configuration.
The [builtin VCL code](https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/browser/bin/varnishd/builtin.vcl) does allow OPTION through.

Try looking through your VCL and look for either specifically disabling OPTIONS method, or enabling only some methods like GET/POST.

If you can't find it, please consider publishing your VCL (of course anonymized, if there is any sensitive information).